# WSDL2CODE maven plugin

Tags: java, web-services, maven, maven-plugin

When using WSDL2CODE maven plugin, classes and resources are being created in target folder, I wanted them to be routed to src and resources folder in webapp, can you please help me in this regard?
Also I see ant config file build.xml being created along with the source and resources in the target folder, why this usually happens?

Please find my maven plugin below.

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>com.xyz</packageName>
                        <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/polupdates.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                        <generateServerSide>true</generateServerSide>
                        <generateServicesXml>true</generateServicesXml>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

I am not good at maven, can you please share me some good guide with respect to web services development with maven.

Answer (score 1):

why you want to put it in the source folder?
By convention, Maven automatically compiles any source files that it finds under the following directory:

> target/generated-sources/

All the Java source file will be compiled along with the generated one and you can find them in the  target/classes folder .Now when you package these all the classes along with the generated one will be ther in the packaging(jar/war)

If you are using an IDE such as Eclipse or Intellij's IDEA and having problem , you need to make sure that the IDE is aware of the generated Java code. For example, in Eclipse it is necessary to add the target/generated-sources/jaxws directory to the project as a source code directory.